# Request.fullpath unless URL contains .json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a RoR snippet that does the following:

```
request.fullpath =~ /\A\/(login|sso_login|sign_out|auth)/
```

This stores the URL unless it is one of the blacklisted URL's.  How can I make this also ignore anything that contains .json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can check if !request.xhr?